# Jquery plugin using second instance's options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I have written a Jquery Pagination plugin that works great with just one instance of the plugin. When I try to use two instances, the first instance ignores its given options and uses the second instance's options. I know this because the two sections both start out with the defined items per page, but when you navigate to another 'page' in the pagination, it reverts to the second instance's `itemsPerPage` - **2**.

My guess is the second time this plugin is called, it is overwriting `$.pagination`'s options, so when either pagination goes to a new page, it uses the overwritten options.

Here's the plugin:

```
/* Jquery Pagination */
(function($){
    $.pagination = {
        defaultOptions : {
            itemsPerPage : 5,
            startPage : 1,
            showNextPrev : true,
            navigationPosition : 'before',
            paginationClass : 'pagination',
            paginationItemClass : 'paginationItem',
            paginationItemActiveClass : 'active',
            nextClass : 'next',
            nextText : 'Next',
            prevClass : 'prev',
            prevText : 'Prev',
        }
    }

    $.fn.extend({
        pagination : function(newOptions){
            var options = $.extend($.pagination.defaultOptions, newOptions),
                itemsToPaginate = $(this),
                itemsToPaginateContainer = itemsToPaginate.eq(0).parent(),
                paginationWrapper = "<div class='" + options.paginationClass + "'></div>",
                paginationControls = '',
                pagination,
                numberOfPages,

            showPage = function(goToPage){
                var page = (typeof goToPage === 'number') ? goToPage : goToPage.attr('href').replace('#page', ''),
                    itemRangeEnd = page * options.itemsPerPage
                    itemRangeStart = itemRangeEnd - options.itemsPerPage;

                $( '.' + options.paginationItemClass, pagination).removeClass(options.paginationItemActiveClass);
                if (typeof goToPage === 'number')
                    pagination.find('.' + options.paginationItemClass).eq(goToPage-1).addClass(options.paginationItemActiveClass);
                else
                    goToPage.addClass(options.paginationItemActiveClass);

                itemsToPaginate.hide().slice(itemRangeStart, itemRangeEnd).show();
            },

            createPagination = (function(){
                // Add pagination element to DOM
                switch(options.navigationPosition.toLowerCase()){
                    /*
                    // TODO: Create ability to insert pagination after or before & after
                    case 'both':
                        itemsToPaginateContainer.before(paginationWrapper);
                        itemsToPaginateContainer.after(paginationWrapper);
                        break;

                    case 'after':
                        itemsToPaginateContainer.after(paginationWrapper);
                        break;
                    */

                    default:
                        itemsToPaginateContainer.before(paginationWrapper);
                        break;
                }

                // Selecting pagination element
                pagination = itemsToPaginateContainer.siblings('.' + options.paginationClass);

                // Count how many pages to make
                numberOfPages = Math.ceil( itemsToPaginate.length / options.itemsPerPage );

                // Insert controls into pagination element
                if(options.showNextPrev) paginationControls += "<a href='#' class='" + options.prevClass + "'>" + options.prevText + "</a>";
                for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
                    paginationControls += "<a href='#page" + i + "' class='" + options.paginationItemClass + "'>" + i + "</a>";
                }
                if(options.showNextPrev) paginationControls += "<a href='#' class='" + options.nextClass + "'>" + options.nextText + "</a>";
                (numberOfPages !== 1) ? pagination.html(paginationControls) : pagination.remove() ;
            }()),

            bindUIEvents = (function(){
                pagination.find('.' + options.paginationItemClass + ':not(.' + options.nextClass + '):not(.' + options.prevClass + ')').on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    showPage( $(this) );
                });

                pagination.find('.' + options.prevClass).on('click', function(){
                    var prevPageIdx = pagination.find('.' + options.paginationItemActiveClass).index() - 1;
                    // console.log(prevPageIdx);
                    if(prevPageIdx < 1)
                        showPage(numberOfPages);
                    else
                        showPage(prevPageIdx);
                });

                pagination.find('.' + options.nextClass).on('click', function(){
                    var nextPageIdx = pagination.find('.' + options.paginationItemActiveClass).index() + 1;
                    if(nextPageIdx > numberOfPages)
                        showPage(1);
                    else
                        showPage(nextPageIdx);
                });
            }());

            showPage(options.startPage);
            return this;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/FvP4k/)

Any idea why each instance of this plugin doesn't just use its own options? How would I need to structure a plugin to encapsulate and protect their own options? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
var options = $.extend($.pagination.defaultOptions, newOptions),
```

To

```
var options = $.extend({}, $.pagination.defaultOptions, newOptions),
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7YkeE/)**

Reason is you are providing the target as defaultOption while using the syntax [jQuery.extend( target [, object1 ] [, objectN ]](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend-target-object1-objectN)

Comment: Wow. I can't believe that is all it takes. I'll be looking up the exact difference between the two ways of using `$.extend()` and posting my findings here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @FillipPeyton You are welcome.. See the syntax in my answer update and link to it.

Comment: It makes sense to me now. I was extending the new options in to the reference of `$.pagination.defaultOptions`, rather than a new object literal all together. Thanks again!