# want to create multiple paginations on the same page using Easy Paginate jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, pagination

[here is the plugin which I am using](http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/#demos)
i tried many things at my level but didn't got the finale desire result,here i want to create two instances which will be separate from each other and their behaviour also be different at their level
what i tried  ,firstly have applied or linked all necessary files as per [plugin](http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/#demos)  html file 
HTML structure

```
    <div id="easyPaginate">
        <img src="img/demo/surf1.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf2.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf3.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf4.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf5.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf6.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf7.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf8.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf9.jpg" />
    </div>

<div id="easyPaginate1">
        <img src="img/demo/surf11.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf12.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf13.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf14.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf15.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf16.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf17.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf18.jpg" />
        <img src="img/demo/surf19.jpg" />
    </div>
```

Java script function's from Script.js file means the simple function which i can add in my html page in script tag

```
$(function() {  
    $('#easyPaginate').easyPaginate1({
        paginateElement: 'a',
        pagination: true,
        loader: true,
        elementsPerPage: 3,
        randomizer: 0.7
    }); 
});
$(function () {
    $('#easyPaginate1').easyPaginate({
        paginateElement: 'a',
        pagination: true,
        loader: true,
        elementsPerPage: 4,
        randomizer: 0.7
        //effect: 'slide'
    });
});
```

and this is external java script file in which the main function is written

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.easyPaginate = function (options) {
        var defaults = {                
            hashPage: 'page',                
            effect: 'default',                
            prevButton: true,
            prevButtonText: 'Prevous',
            nextButton: true,
            nextButtonText: 'Next'
        }

        return this.each(function (instance) {

            var plugin = Object;
            plugin.el = $(this);
            plugin.el.addClass('easyPaginateList');

            plugin.settings = {
                pages: 0,
                objElements: Object,
                currentPage: 1
            }

            var getNbOfPages = function () {
                return Math.ceil(plugin.settings.objElements.length / plugin.settings.elementsPerPage);
            };

            var displayNav = function () {
                htmlNav = '<div class="easyPaginateNav arrow-box">';


                //for (i = 1; i <= plugin.settings.pages; i++) {
                //    htmlNav += '<a href="#' + plugin.settings.hashPage + ':' + i + '" title="Page ' + i + '" rel="' + i + '" class="page">' + i + '</a>';
                //};

                if (plugin.settings.prevButton) {

                    htmlNav += '<a href="" title="Previous" rel="" class="prev">' + plugin.settings.prevButtonText + '</a>';

                    //<a href="#" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('arrow1left','','images/list-docs-arrow-right-on.png',1)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"><img src="images/list-docs-arrow-right-off.png" border="0" id="arrow1left"></a>
                    //htmlNav += '<a href="" title="Previous" rel="" class="prev" ' + onMouseOver + '="MM_swapImage(' + arrow1left + ',' + ',' + images / list - docs - arrow - right - on.png + ',1)" ' + onMouseOut + '=' + "MM_swapImgRestore()" > ' ' + plugin.settings.prevButtonText + '</a>';
                }

                if (plugin.settings.nextButton) {
                    htmlNav += '<a href="" title="Next" rel="" class="next">' + plugin.settings.nextButtonText + '</a>';
                }


                htmlNav += '</div>';
                plugin.nav = $(htmlNav);
                //plugin.nav.css({
                //    'width': plugin.el.width()
                //});
                plugin.el.after(plugin.nav);

                $('.easyPaginateNav a.page, .easyPaginateNav a.first, .easyPaginateNav a.last', plugin).on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    displayPage($(this).attr('rel'));
                });

                $('.easyPaginateNav a.prev', plugin).on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    page = plugin.settings.currentPage > 1 ? parseInt(plugin.settings.currentPage) - 1 : 1;
                    displayPage(page);
                });

                $('.easyPaginateNav a.next', plugin).on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    page = plugin.settings.currentPage < plugin.settings.pages ? parseInt(plugin.settings.currentPage) + 1 : plugin.settings.pages;
                    displayPage(page);
                });
            };

            var displayPage = function (page, forceEffect) {
                if (plugin.settings.currentPage != page) {
                    plugin.settings.currentPage = parseInt(page);
                    offsetStart = (page - 1) * plugin.settings.elementsPerPage;
                    offsetEnd = page * plugin.settings.elementsPerPage;
                    if (typeof (forceEffect) != 'undefined') {
                        eval("transition_" + forceEffect + "(" + offsetStart + ", " + offsetEnd + ")");
                    } else {
                        eval("transition_" + plugin.settings.effect + "(" + offsetStart + ", " + offsetEnd + ")");
                    }

                    plugin.nav.find('.current').removeClass('current');
                    plugin.nav.find('a.page:eq(' + (page - 1) + ')').addClass('current');

                    switch (plugin.settings.currentPage) {
                        case 1:
                            $('.easyPaginateNav a', plugin).removeClass('disabled');
                            $('.easyPaginateNav a.first, .easyPaginateNav a.prev', plugin).addClass('disabled');
                            break;
                        case plugin.settings.pages:
                            $('.easyPaginateNav a', plugin).removeClass('disabled');
                            $('.easyPaginateNav a.last, .easyPaginateNav a.next', plugin).addClass('disabled');
                            break;
                        default:
                            $('.easyPaginateNav a', plugin).removeClass('disabled');
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };

            var transition_default = function (offsetStart, offsetEnd) {
                plugin.currentElements.hide();
                plugin.currentElements = plugin.settings.objElements.slice(offsetStart, offsetEnd).clone();
                plugin.el.html(plugin.currentElements);
                plugin.currentElements.show();
            };

            var transition_fade = function (offsetStart, offsetEnd) {
                plugin.currentElements.fadeOut();
                plugin.currentElements = plugin.settings.objElements.slice(offsetStart, offsetEnd).clone();
                plugin.el.html(plugin.currentElements);
                plugin.currentElements.fadeIn();
            };

            var transition_slide = function (offsetStart, offsetEnd) {
                plugin.currentElements.animate({
                    'margin-left': plugin.settings.slideOffset * -1,
                    'opacity': 0
                }, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

                plugin.currentElements = plugin.settings.objElements.slice(offsetStart, offsetEnd).clone();
                plugin.currentElements.css({
                    'margin-left': plugin.settings.slideOffset,
                    'display': 'block',
                    'opacity': 0,
                    'min-width': plugin.el.width() / 2
                });
                plugin.el.html(plugin.currentElements);
                plugin.currentElements.animate({
                    'margin-left': 0,
                    'opacity': 1
                });
            };

            var transition_climb = function (offsetStart, offsetEnd) {
                plugin.currentElements.each(function (i) {
                    var $objThis = $(this);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $objThis.animate({
                            'margin-left': plugin.settings.slideOffset * -1,
                            'opacity': 0
                        }, function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }, i * 200);
                });

                plugin.currentElements = plugin.settings.objElements.slice(offsetStart, offsetEnd).clone();
                plugin.currentElements.css({
                    'margin-left': plugin.settings.slideOffset,
                    'display': 'block',
                    'opacity': 0,
                    'min-width': plugin.el.width() / 2
                });
                plugin.el.html(plugin.currentElements);
                plugin.currentElements.each(function (i) {
                    var $objThis = $(this);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $objThis.animate({
                            'margin-left': 0,
                            'opacity': 1
                        });
                    }, i * 200);
                });
            };

            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            plugin.currentElements = $([]);
            plugin.settings.objElements = plugin.el.find(plugin.settings.paginateElement);
            plugin.settings.pages = getNbOfPages();
            if (plugin.settings.pages > 1) {
                plugin.el.html();

                // Here we go
                displayNav();

                page = 1;
                if (document.location.hash.indexOf('#' + plugin.settings.hashPage + ':') != -1) {
                    page = parseInt(document.location.hash.replace('#' + plugin.settings.hashPage + ':', ''));
                    if (page.length <= 0 || page < 1 || page > plugin.settings.pages) {
                        page = 1;
                    }
                }

                displayPage(page, 'default');
            }
        });
    };

})
(jQuery);
```

here what i am getting is,the arrows or navigations from one instance affects the both div's means from click of next or prev from any single instance ,that slides elements from both instances,so how do i resolved this issue??

Comment: Where us `$.easyPaginate1` defined?

Comment: here one external js file in which these both functions have added n the main defination of the function is written in external js file which is ilnked to html page

Comment: <script src="lib/jquery.easyPaginate.js"></script> file in which the function defination has wrtten
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>  this the file in which the functions are called with require attributes,

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for it?

Comment: actually i dont know ,how to create fiddle,sorry

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/7bvpp826/8/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=7bvpp826,check this one,which is exactly identical to what i want,but that also not working for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110634/jquery-plugin-using-second-instances-options -useful link